# How can one tell the parent pid of a process , out of that process?

Tags: c, linux, process

I know `getppid` retrieves the parent pid of the underlying program, but how can you tell this out of that program? I can't find anything useful in `/proc/[pid]`, or is there any useful API that i can use?

**UPDATE**

I mean , i'm inspecting these procress with another process , so getppid won't work here

Comment: Typography hint: there are no spaces before punctuation, like comma, question marks, etc.

Comment: @Jens that's a bug , i high-lighted the part , there's no space between ']' and the ', or' ..

Comment: No, I mean in all the English text you write, like after "I mean", "a bug", "the part".

Comment: @Jens , oh okay , i'll take the advice , it's more of a personal habit to add spaces in codes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the fourth field in /proc/[pid]/stat. It is documented in the man page `proc(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

That information is present in `/proc/<pid>/stat`, and more readably in `/proc/<pid>/status`:

```
$ grep PPid /proc/$$/status
PPid:   10615
$ awk '{print $4}' /proc/$$/stat
10615
$ ps -ef
...
me 10616 10615  0 11:04 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```